# get child <a> @href atrribute inside <ul> ancestor, only when <li> string-length() is higher than 20 chars

Tags: xml, google-sheets, xpath, google-sheets-formula

Using `=IMPORTXML()` in Google Sheets, I want to extract the `@href` attribute from an `<a>` that is inside a `<li>` of an `<ul>` using XPath, only if the `<li>` `string-length()` is above 20 characters.

Example:

```html
<html>

<head>...</head>

<body>
  ...
  <ul>
    <li>123456<a href="google.com">78</a>90123456789</li>
    <!-- 19 chars !-->
    <li>123456789<a href="bing.com">0123</a>45</li>
    <!-- 15 chars !-->
    <li>12345<a href="yahoo.com">6789012</a>345678901234567890</li> <!-- 30 chars !-->
  </ul>
  ...
</body>

</html>
```

Here, I would like to receive only yahoo.com, as the containing `<li>` is the only one in the list that is above 20 characters.

I did not find an XPath syntax that works for me. Any suggestions?

Comment: XML and HTML are not exactly the same.  You should be using an HTMLparser and not a XML parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return the a's href attribute of all li elements, that are immediate children of ul elements, having li node string length greater than 20:

```
//ul/li[string-length(.)>20]/a/@href
```

which selects for your example:

```
href="yahoo.com"
```

if you just need the string:

```
//ul/li[string-length(.)>20]/a/@href/string()
```

which selects:

```
yahoo.com
```

Comment: Thank you @David Denenberg. I tried to apply the same logic for my specific situation and it does not work. In my case, the condition described in this question is one of a set of conditions that should apply to the `<a>` element. My path looks more like this: `//a[ancestor-or-self::p or ancestor-or-self::ol or ancestor-or-self::ul/li[string-length(.)>20]`. In this form - all `<a>` elements are considered

Comment: Perhaps you should have been more specific what you are trying to accomplish.  You asked a very specific question for which I provided a concise and accurate answer.  If you are trying to combine this with other conditions and need help understanding how to use this simple predicate in combination with your other requirements, then please frame the question that way.

Comment: You are right, I did not think that would effect the answer, as my knowledge in this field is somewhat limited. Should I edit this question or open another one and close the current one with the provided answer?

Comment: Probably fine to deal with in comments if you can describe concisely what combination of conditions you are trying to achieve.  Thanks.

Comment: Generally, I want to extract all linkes in a given page that are not in menus. For the simplicity, lets say only links from `<p>`, `<ol>` and `<ul>` that are below 20 chars (to avoid menu items, which are generally short)

Comment: Assuming you only want the 20 character restriction to apply to ul/li and not p and not ol, then something like this will work `//*[((self::li and ancestor::ul and string-length(.)>20) or self::p or self::ol) ]//a/@href/string()`.  Keeping your kind of approach, try: `//a[ancestor::p or ancestor::ol or (ancestor::li[ancestor::ul and string-length(.)>20])]`  Not sure how concerned you are with whether the ul is an immediate ancestor of li.